# Can I override a specific key on my keyboard permanently to always enter the @ symbol?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

The problem is (and this really sucks) that every so often (without apparent reason) the alternate keys are not working on my keyboard. I really tried EVERYTHING (keyboard layout, keyboard manufacturer support, Microsoft support several times, ...), did not work. So the main problem is that in that case I can't press the @ which is totally annoying. So I was wondering if I could just force my keyboard to A-L-W-A-Y-S generate an @ when I press AltGr+2?

I tried Microsoft PowerToys but there I can just assign keys on the keyboard, not symbols. So this does not help. It is probably possible with AutoHotkey, but I am not familiar how to do that with this advanced tool. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To get familiar with AutoHotkey read the [**Beginner Tutorial**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).
- [**Create a script**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s12) and add this code to it:

  ```
  <^>!2::Send @
  ```

**<^>!** is the symbol for **[AltGr](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#AltGr)**

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but I finally got the chance to test it out, and with `<^>!2::Send @` it does NOT work unfortunately, but when I use `<^>!2::Send X@`, I actually DO get the "X", but not the "@", can this still be fixed somehow? And what's strange, when I use ALT+64, the "@" works - could I make AutoHotkey just make "pressing" the ALT version instead?

Comment: `<^>!2::Send {ASC 64}` works! :)